# Nginx and multiple domains

Tags: node.js, nginx

I bought some domains at `godaddy.com` (i.e `mydomain.com`) for my droplet at `digitalocean.com` (i.e `199.216.110.210`). I run a nodejs application on port 80 on the droplet. From `godaddy.com`, I forward with masking mydomain.com to `199.216.110.210` and I could see may app.

Now I want to run on `199.216.110.210` several node applications on different ports, using ngnix as reverse proxy. I followed the instructions here (`www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-host-multiple-node-js-applications-on-a-single-vps-with-nginx-forever-and-crontab`).

My nginx .conf file is

```
 server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mydomain.com;
    location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    # same as in the link above
    }   
}
```

(and I am sure it is read: when ngnix start if I put an error there, ngnix reports it).

I start the nodejs application on port 3000:

- I try `mydomain.com`, but ngnix shows always the welcome page.
- Also doing `mydomain.com: 3000` does not work,
- it works only with `199.216.110.210:3000`.

From godaddy.com, if I forward with masking the `mydomain.com` to `199.216.110.210:3000` I can see may app.
But I do not like this solution. I would like domains pointing to my droplet, without specifing the port and admin them with nginx.

How can I get a domain name to use with ngnix as reverse proxy to select my apps, mapped on different domains on different ports? I suppose that forwarding from godaddy.com is somehow limited.

Comment: what does this have to do with node.js?

Comment: Are you doing www.mydomain.com instead of simply mydomain.com in the browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your server go to `/var/log/nginx` and do a `tail -F *log`. Now in another shell restart nginx.

I suspect that your domain name is too long and nginx will complain about its hash_bucket_size is too small. If this is the case open `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` and make sure that the line

`server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;`

exists, has a value of 64 and is uncommented. Then do `sudo service nginx reload`, and check if all works as expected.

Comment: I uncommented it and the redirection works; if I redirect port 4000 to the nodejs app running at port 3000, it works. But on port 80 I got the message from the log: `conflicting server name "day2log.com" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored`

Comment: You have two entries in your config listening for day2log.com on port 80.

Comment: Yes, you were right; I commented in ngnix.conf `#include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;` and it works on port 80

Answer (score 0):

I am going to detail step by step how I am able to do it in my aws ec2 instance;

1. I set up a DNS record to my instance, so i can set `mydomain.com` to `192.168.123.123` (my specific IP).
2. Inside my instance I have forever running my node.js app in port 3000 (I test it work by issuing `curl localhost:3000` from the command line)
3. I then download [this `.sh`](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/renatoargh/dda1fbc854f7957ec7b3/raw/c0bc1a1ec76e50cdb4336182c53a0b222edb6c0e/start.sh) file in order to properly intantiate nginx; `curl -o nginxStarter.sh https://gist.githubusercontent.com/renatoargh/dda1fbc854f7957ec7b3/raw/c0bc1a1ec76e50cdb4336182c53a0b222edb6c0e/start.sh`
4. I configure nginx with [this configuration file](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/renatoargh/dda1fbc854f7957ec7b3/raw/c0176a4b18f517e7b7705d7865d15a92cbff7471/confNginx.nginx). Put this file in; `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`
5. Start nginx with this command; `sudo sh nginxStarter.sh start`

PS.: For multiple apps just replicate the lines that routes the requests to specific ports, very easy...! If not needed you can eliminate lines regarding out SSL.

Comment: I tried this, but the original nginxStarter.sh does nto work on ubuntu. I worked around it changing  functions and network path, but I still get this error: grep: unrecognized option '--with-cc-opt='-g'
and $Starting nginx: nginxStarter.sh: 54: nginxStarter.sh: daemon: not found

Comment: In fact I use it on Amazon Linux (Cent OS)! :/